# How to combine rows in Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, join, amazon-redshift

I am using Amazon redshift.
How do I combine the result of the columns.

If the original rows are:

```
*ID   Name  Color
----------------
1   John   White
1   John   Black
2   Mark   Blue
2   Mark   Red*
```

the result should be:

```
*ID   Name  Color
----------------
1   John   White Black
2   Mark   Blue Red*
```

Comment: Amazon Redshift is based on Postgres. How can a MySQL answer for `group_concat` be relevant? or a "duplicate"? @FancyPants +1

Comment: @Used_By_Already I don't know anything about amazon redshift, but the question was and still is tagged as mysql.

Comment: @FancyPants good point, so I changed that. Mark: please only use tags that are relevant to this question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Redshift provides a function LISTAGG() for what you need

```
SELECT id, name, LISTAGG(Color,' ') AS Colors
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY id, name
```

> For each group in a query, the LISTAGG aggregate function orders the
>   rows for that group according to the ORDER BY expression, then
>   concatenates the values into a single string.
>   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html

```
SELECT id, name
 , LISTAGG(Color,' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name) AS Colors
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY id, name
```